# How to properly import org.w3c.dom on a Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, dom, import

I need to import the package org.w3c.dom in a Java class used on a Maven project in order to parse an XML document

I've tried importing the package and adding the org.w3c.dom to the dependencies in pom.xml but I just can't seem to get it right. Here is the parts of the code of the .java and the pom.xml related to this problem:

------------------------------------StatsCommand.java------------------------

```
import org.w3c.dom;
```

--------------------------------------pom.xml---------------------

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.w3c/dom -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.w3c</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0-jaxb-1.0.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.w3c</groupId>
    <artifactId>epubcheck</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Whenever I run $mvn clean install, in order to try the changes I made to the app, I'll get the following error:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.357 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-05-22T09:15:26+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project foo-app: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/victor/Descargas/onos/foo-app/src/main/java/org/foo/app/StatsCommand.java:[57,15] **package org.w3c does not exist**


How could I fix this?
```

Comment: You show part of file  `App.java` but error points class `StatsCommand.java` post this file too

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot the name of my Java class. It's the code from StatsCommand, I will edit it now.

Comment: You import _classes_ not _packages_!

Comment: Really sucks when you make such an obvious mistake. Changed the import for "import org.w3c.dom.*" and it looks like it's working now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
```

Dependency is as follows

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.w3c/dom -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.w3c</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0-jaxb-1.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```